# Why does docker create containers while building images?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Why does docker start a container for every command in Dockerfile?
**I understand a new layer is created for every command.**

```
Step 1/3 : FROM nginx:latest
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
8ec398bc0356: Pull complete 
dfb2a46f8c2c: Pull complete 
b65031b6a2a5: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:8aa7f6a9585d908a63e5e418dc5d14ae7467d2e36e1ab4f0d8f9d059a3d071ce
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
 ---> c7460dfcab50
Step 2/3 : WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
 ---> Running in f8adb5dc5a47
Removing intermediate container f8adb5dc5a47
 ---> a59fb35a43c2
Step 3/3 : COPY . .
 ---> 7911d9a451d9
Successfully built 7911d9a451d9
Successfully tagged mynginx:latest
```

What is the point of creating a new container and setting WORKDIR in it when you are gonna remove that container anyway?

**Notice** this line `Removing intermediate container f8adb5dc5a47`

Answer (score 2):

For each line daemon creates a new image and each instruction runs independently. Docker Daemon uses intermediate images to accelerate the docker build process. Build cache indicates this.

Comment: I am already aware of that Sanket. If you notice carefully you will see it runs containers in the build process.

Answer (score 2):

Think about how you would create a image without using `Dockerfile` from an existing docker image. You would create a container from the image, do some stuff inside the container and then [`commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) the container which creates the new image.

This is what `docker build` is doing. It creates a container from the previous layer(`FROM` is the previous layer for first instruction), runs the current instruction inside the container and commits this modified container as new image layer.

Comment: WORKDIR is basically a cd. If you cd inside a container, what are you really commiting? And once you kill the container what did you really achieve by changing directory inside a container?

Comment: WORKDIR is not just cd. If the directory doesn't exist, it will be created

Comment: I know that, in my case it is present. Also what is the point of making a directory in a container and kill it?

Comment: An image with an extra directory is different from an image without it.  WORKDIR is like any other instruction in the Dockerfile. Why does it surprise you that you need a container to execute it and save the resulting image? Once the image is saved, the container is not needed anymore so it is killed.

Comment: I already have that directory present. In-fact every container created from nginx image has that directory present. All we are doing it is setting that directory as the current directory

Comment: You can pull an nginx image and verify it, if you want

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have the directory present or not. That is how docker build executes any instruction. How does it know if the directory is present or not without first creating a container?

Comment: every layer only stores diff from the last layer, it doesn't need to start a container to figure out the changes in file system

Comment: You can check these diffs in /var/lib/dockeroverlay2

Comment: So you want `docker build` to handle the case of WORKDIR being already present as a special case by traversing all the layers above on disk instead of just starting a container and treating the instruction just like any other instruction?

Comment: Let me explain you the problem. So I have 2 operations 1. I go into a directory 2. I copy something there. If you make a container for cd and then make another container for copy which is supposed to copy files in a directory I CDed in last container, you will have to go into the directory again. If I have misunderstood please tell me how does docker handles these 2 operations in two different containers layer by layer

Comment: docker also stores metadata about each image and this metadata includes the working directory. You can see the metadata with `docker image inspect <image>`. Try to identify the image created by the WORKDIR instruction and run `docker image inspect` on it. You would see that docker knows the working directory for that image. So when container is created for next instruction from previous image(copy in your question), docker knows to which working directory it has to copy.